# Why does starting StreamingContext fail with "IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I deployed master and workers on spark. When I try to strat some computations with SparkStreaming it fails. I created StreamingContext in sbt console.

Please see below, the Error message, sample code, build.sbt and the command to run the program

---

### ERROR message

```
ERROR StreamingContext: Error starting the context, 
marking it as stopped
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations 
registered, so nothing to execute
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
...
```

---

### CODE

```
/* StreamingEx.scala */
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ Seconds, StreamingContext }

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://169.254.112.244:7077").setAppName("TestingStreaming")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 5577)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

---

### built.sbt

```
name := "StreamingEx"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
val sparkVersion = "2.1.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided"
```

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute

That's the issue exactly, i.e. "no output operations registered", which are operations registered using `DStream` "actions" like [print](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream@print():Unit) (highlighting mine).

> **print(): Unit** Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream. This is an **output operator**, so this DStream will be registered as an output stream and there materialized.

With that, that boils down to the following line just before `ssc.start()`:

```
wordCounts.print()
```

See the Spark official documentation's [Output Operations on DStreams](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams):

> **Output operations** allow DStream's data to be pushed out to external systems like a database or a file systems. Since the output operations actually allow the transformed data to be consumed by external systems, they trigger the actual execution of all the DStream transformations (similar to actions for RDDs).

Comment: I added wordCounts.print() and it failed with this error

ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1514212805000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 98.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 98.0 (TID 262, 169.254.112.244, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastExce
ption: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spa
rk.rdd.ShuffledRDD